# extjs store with ajax serving multi read requests

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

Unanswered: store ajax serving multi read requests (best practice question)

Hi, im trying to understand the proper design concept of Store proxies using the Ajax api config and have a question on how this should be done.

suppose i have a store which has a server proxy using the Ext.data.proxy.Ajax class and i have an api with the following:

```
proxy: {
   type: 'ajax',
   api: {
       read: 'some/something/list.json',
       create: 'some/something/insert.json',
       update: 'some/something/update.json',
       destroy: 'some/something/destroy.json'
   }
}
```

now suppose my read is triggered by a search button and when i have a blank text box and click search it makes a request through the read api to retrieve the list.json. but i want to have another read as part of the same store / api to read individual records say something like this:

```
read: 'some/something/<field_value>.json'
```

my proxy read is already assigned to the list.json but i want to allow the same store proxy to be able to read from individual record searches also. granted that i cant have two read statements in my proxy. how would I go about writing this?

help me understand? maybe my server controller has to be able to determine by keyword @PathVariable if path is list i.e .json then call the list db query otherwise if .json then run the individual search query through the db.?? and if so what would be the read: url?

whats the best way to design and build this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider using [`setExtraParam`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-method-setExtraParam) instead of changing the URL path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read single record instead of defining proxy in store you should do it in Model and then call load on model itself something like below.

```
    Ext.define('app.model.User', { 
    {
    fields: [
    { name: 'LoginUserId', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'FirstName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' }],

    proxy: 
    {
    type: 'rest',
    url: '/User',
    reader: 
    {
    type: 'json',
    root: ''
    }
    }
    });

var user = Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('app.model.User');
    user.load(123, {
        success: function(userObj) {

        }
    });
```